# Why is my python module path wrong which add an extra directory

Tags: python, sys.path

Here is my project structure in directory **/home/clark/workspace/**

[image]
In my `analyzer` file, I import module
`from logger import log_manager`, the module path should be **logger.log_manager** but **essay_scoring_service.logger.log_manager**
[image]
[image]